# Do elements $x^2$ and $y$ commute in group $G = \langle x,y \mid x^4, y^{10}, xyx^{-1}y^{-3} \rangle?$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Do elements $x^2$ and $y$ commute in group$$ G =\langle x,y \mid x^4, y^{10}, xyx^{-1}y^{-3} \rangle?$$

Here's what I could get

$$\begin{align}
x^2y& = xxy\\
& = xy^3x \\
&= xyy^2x\\
& = y^3xy^2x \\
&= y^3xyyx \\
& = y^6xyx \\
&= y^9x^2.
\end{align}$$

Then $yx^2y = x^2$.

Now let's assume that $x^2y = yx^2$, then $yx^2y = y^2x^2$ and I get that $y^2 = 1$.  I think that $y^2 = 1$ is bad in this group. And that's where I am stuck.

So what can I do next to prove that it is impossible?

Comment: Apart from WhatsUp's complete description of the group, an alternative quick way of doing this is to observe that the permutations $x=(2,4,5,3)$ and $y=(1,2,3,4,5)$ satisfy the group relations with $y^2 \ne 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group $G$ is the quotient of the free group $A = \langle X, Y\rangle$ by the normal subgroup $B$ generated by the elements $X^4, Y^{10}, XYX^{-1}Y^{-3}$. We identify $x, y\in G$ with the images of $X, Y \in A$.

We will show that $G$ is isomorphic to the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $H = \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z \rtimes_\phi \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, where $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ acts on $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ via the action $\phi:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \rightarrow (\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z)^\times$ sending $1$ to $3$.

This is mostly tautological. Firstly, we construct a homomorphism $F:A \rightarrow H$ sending $X$ to $(0, 1)\in H$ and $Y$ to $(1, 0) \in H$. It is clear that all the three generators of $B$ are sent to the neutral element of $H$, hence $F$ induces a homomorphism $f$ from the quotient $G$ to $H$.

Secondly, we construct $g: H \rightarrow G$ sending $(1, 0)$ to $Y$ and $(0, 1)$ to $X$. The relations in $G$ exactly ensures that $g$ is well-defined.

Finally, it is obvious that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other.

Therefore $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, and we see immediately that $y^2 \neq 1$ in $G$, since its image in $H$ is not the neutral element.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note that in general, if $G$ has presentation $\langle g_1, \ldots, g_m \mid r_1, \ldots, r_a \rangle$ and $H$ has presentation $\langle h_1, \ldots, h_n \mid s_1, \ldots, s_b \rangle$, and $\phi : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$, then $G \rtimes_\phi H$ has presentation $\langle g_1, \ldots, g_m, h_1, \ldots, h_n \mid r_1, \ldots, r_a, s_1, \ldots, s_b, g_1 h_1 g_1^{-1} \phi(g_1)(h_1)^{-1}, \ldots, g_m h_n g_m^{-1} \phi(g_m)(h_n)^{-1}$, where the last block has $ab$ elements $g_i h_j g_i^{-1} \phi(g_i)(h_j)^{-1}$.

Comment: Then the question's group presentation can be immediately recognized as a presentation of this form.

Comment: (With, of course, the restriction that $\{ g_1, \ldots, g_m \}$ and $\{ h_1, \ldots, h_n \}$ have to be disjoint sets of symbols.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes. I just explained in detail why this is true for this particular example.